# How to clear Content of WebBrowser control using as HTML Editor?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i open the HTML Editor (WebBrowser) again after i used it one time to save the Text, it contains the Old written Content. How to clean the content?

I tried to set the Document Content (like when i am loading the entrys of the database) as `HTMLEditor.Document.Write("");` but it doesn't work.

So i am loading the Form containing the WebControl as FrameEditor `viewer = new FrameEditor();` but it doesn't help.

i tried to `set _doc = null;` _doc is IHTMLDocument2 and `_doc = modernHTMLEditor.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;`

i tried to reload the HTMLEditor as `HTMLEditor = new WebBrowser();`

```
private IHTMLDocument2 _doc;

private void viewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_doc = null;                                    
modernHTMLEditor.DocumentText = "<html><body></body></html>";
_doc =
modernHTMLEditor.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
modernHTMLEditor.Document.Write(DocText);
_doc.designMode = "On";
modernHTMLEditor.Document.ExecCommand("FontName", false, "Arial");
FontSizeSetup();
FontTypeSetup();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer.
It's the use of:
    _doc.open("");
before declaring the designMode = "On";

Comment: But i recommend using GeckoFX or CefSharp and implement Summernote (and with it Jquery and Bootstrap) or something like this.